# problem while trying to display image from database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to display a row from my database by `id`, the data displayed successfully but the image doesn't show (showing a broken link icon).

Here is the `index.blade.php` where the `href` to the row:

```html
<a href="singlepost/{{$products->id}}">
<img src="storage/{{$templates->image_path2}}">
```

The route:

```php
Route::get('/singlepost/{id}', 'App\http\controllers\TemplatesController@getPostById')->name('single.post');
```

The function `getPostById`

```php
public function getPostById($id){
    $products = DB::table('templates')->where('id', $id)->first();

    return view('singlepost', compact('products'));
}
```

The `singlepage.blade.php`

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <img src="storage/{{$products->image_path}}">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7">
        <h2>{{$products->name}}</h2>
        <p>{{$products->description}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the image link you are getting ? Right click on the broken image icon and click `copy image address` and paste it here please

Comment: Your current src is relative `src="storage...`, add a slash before `storage`, or try with the asset helper `<img src="{{ asset('storage'.$products->image_path) }}">`.

Comment: here is the link (http://127.0.0.1:8000/singlepost/storage/lsfP4wxmQQDX4rOYhRBmwln12zoKoQ3lknvjPhoL.webp) @matiaslauriti

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ i tried this before but it doesn't worked

Comment: Did you run the `php artisan storage:link` command? Is the file stored in `your-project/storage/app/public` directory?

Comment: This is a VERY GOOD youtube tutorial to learn Storage link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=midsdlBXj-o ... Storage link is handy and easy, but you must learn how it works...

Answer (score 1):

When referencing publically accessible files, you want to do so from the `/public/storage` directory. Files from the `/storage/app/public` directory should be mapped from this directory to `/public/storage` using a symbloic link,

You create the `symlink` using:

```sh
php artisan storage:link
```

With that done, assets in `/storage/app/public` can now be accessed as if they existed in `/public/storage`. Use the [`asset`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-asset) helper to get your image.

```html
<img src="{{ asset($templates->image_path2) }}" alt="Some alt tag ..." />
```

The above assumes a relative path of the asset from the `/public/storage` root, if you had the image in a subdirectory you would need to include that too.

For example, if you had your images in an `img` subdirectoy:

```html
<img src="{{ asset('/img/' . $templates->image_path2) }}" alt="Some alt tag ..." />
```